# Error submitting Sales Order to Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I'm testing an order submission via Postman, just passing this JSON structure to /SalesOrders.

```
{
    "Details": [
        {
            "InventoryID": {
                "value": "TEST-SKU"
            },
            "WarehouseID": {
                "value": "BUF"
            },
            "LineNbr": {
                "value": 1
            },
            "OrderQty": {
                "value": 2
            },
            "UnitPrice": {
                "value": 285
            }
        }
    ],
    "CustomerID": {
        "value": "0000003759"
    },
    "Hold": {
        "value": false
    },
    "Description": {
        "value": "WEBTEST-1000123456"
    },
    "ExternalRef": {
        "value": "1000123456"
    },
    "BillToAddressOverride": {
        "value": true
    },
    "ShipToAddressOverride": {
        "value": true
    },
    "Totals": {
        "FreightCostIsuptodate": {
            "value": true
        },
        "OverrideFreightPrice": {
            "value": true
        },
        "FreightCost": {
            "value": 41.89
        },
        "Freight": {
            "value": 41.89
        }
    },
    "PaymentMethod": {
        "value": "APSCRCARD"
    },
    "NewCard": {
        "value": true
    },
    "PaymentCardIdentifier": {
        "value": "APSCRCARD:****-****-****-1234"
    },
    "PaymentRef": {
        "value": "12345678910"
    },
    "ShipToContact": {
        "Attention": {
            "value": "Test User"
        },
        "BusinessName": {
            "value": "Testing Company"
        }
    },
    "BillToAddress": {
        "AddressLine1": {
            "value": "123 Test Lane"
        },
        "AddressLine2": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "AddressLine3": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "AddressLine4": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "City": {
            "value": "Buffalo"
        },
        "Country": {
            "value": "US"
        },
        "PostalCode": {
            "value": "14216"
        },
        "State": {
            "value": "NY"
        },
        "rowNumber": {
            "value": 1
        }
    },
    "ShipToAddress": {
        "AddressLine1": {
            "value": "123 Test Lane"
        },
        "AddressLine2": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "AddressLine3": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "AddressLine4": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "City": {
            "value": "Buffalo"
        },
        "Country": {
            "value": "US"
        },
        "PostalCode": {
            "value": "14216"
        },
        "State": {
            "value": "NY"
        },
        "rowNumber": {
            "value": 1
        }
    },
    "ShippingSettings": {
        "shipVia": {
            "value": "BUFFEDEX2DAY"
        }
    }
}
```

It's getting hung up when I'm trying to pass over cc information and I'm not exactly sure what to do.  It says the Payment Card Identifier field is empty but as you can see I'm passing a value to it.

```
"SalesOrder.PaymentCardIdentifier: 'Identifier' cannot be empty.\nInserting  'CustomerPaymentMethodC' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors."
```

I'm not sure if I need to be using a different value but I'm repurposing one that I received on a call to get Sales Orders from Acumatica.

I was curious if I potentially have to add the CustomerPaymentMethod before adding the order?  Any help around this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to add this from the UI in Acumatica?  I typically add a CustomerPaymentMethod for the customer since there typically needs to be Cash Account assigned to the payment.

Answer (score 0):

The Validation message mentions **SalesOrder.PaymentCardIdentifier** being empty not **PaymentCardIdentifier** so are you sure you have the correct request format?

Comment: Yes I believe so - the format is working for other sales orders in this same way, just not ones that include a Payment Method.

Comment: Maybe contact their support team ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Endpoint to see how this field is being defined in the SalesOrder Entity. That field is not part of the default endpoint - so I can't check it, but perhaps the name is spelled differently.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out, regarding this, that I was referencing an incorrect endpoint in our system (a custom one as opposed to Default).

I also had to add payment to the Payment sub-object as opposed to the Sales Order object directly.

Thank you everyone for the assistance!